# Cant connect to public dns address on EC2 instance, but public ip works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Unable to connect to the public DNS associated with an EC2 instance. Attached security group to the instance, has all ips open on all ports. Able to connect through the public ip. If more info is needed, please ask.

Comment: This is not a programming question so it's [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's probably worth checking https://status.aws.amazon.com

Comment: are u using the public dns or the private dns hostname

Comment: public dns hostname

Comment: Are you able to resolve that public DNS hostname?